# Issue with Sharepoint 2010 site - read permissions do not allow a user to view a page?

Tags: permissions

Viewers cannot access a site unless they have contribute permission - read does not allow them to access the site?

Ideas?

Comment: I think... u need to check the permission for the page...

Comment: THanks Paddy we have - all pages have been set to Read - but none work unless we have contribute for all??

Comment: Was there any solution? I starting to think it's bad design, but I also have this issue.
Contribute is the selection I need to use if I want people to simply see what's listed in a library. Seems like an overkill for something that should be pretty simple. Thanks in advance! ![out of the box settings](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1lIx.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

A common cause to this is that you have not published your master page or page layouts or other depending artefacts of the page the users are trying to access.

Comment: I've encountered this with minimal customization... no custom master page, web parts, or even modified content. The site/web is provisioned automatically through the API, and the permission group in question is created through the API as well, but uses an default/unmodified "Read" permission level / role assignment - I guess I could put more detail in a question, if you need it, but any idea how to figure out exactly what is being denied access?

Answer (score 0):

"Read" is a permission level created for a site by default. The exact behavior of a permission level is determined by the permissions included in it(You can have permission level called 'Read' and still make it behave like an admin)

Make sure that the 'Read' permission level in your site actually has Read Permissions. 
Follow these steps : Site Settings>Site Permissions>Click 'Permission levels' in ribbon>Click 'Read'>Ensure it has correct list and site permissions for viewing(For example,"View pages in a Web site")

You can also fine tune here how your 'Read' permission level will behave.

Also, Ensure that the master page you are using have at least 1 published version. Same should be true for all the script, css or any other files which are referenced.